# button onclick="e.preventDefault(); return true;" gives e is not defined in browser console

Tags: javascript, html

This is my button element:

```
<button id="loginButton" 
    ...
    onclick="e.preventDefault(); return true;"/>
```

But this approach gives me after login button click error in console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: `e` is not defined

Do you know how to fix my button to avoid "`e` is not defined" error in console?

Comment: try to use `event` instead of `e`

Comment: with event instead of e - i cannot log to application, nothing happens after 'login' click

Comment: why something should happens? The script only prevents default action and do nothing. So, when nothing happens - it works as intended.

Comment: But i cannot login into application if i change e -> event

Comment: yes, because `event.preventDefault();` prevents default action (submitting the form or whatever it is) of the event. I.e. it starts working. Your question is not about logging in. It is about _Uncaught ReferenceError_

Answer (score 3):

`e` is a variable commonly used in event handlers. However you never defined `e` in your code. I recommend using an event listener in JS.

```
    document.getElementById('loginButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return true;
    });
```

This will accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 2):

in events (like `onclick="..."`) you can specify either a function name, then this function has to have a single parameter, where the event object will be passed.
Or you can specify an JavaScript expression (as in your case), in this case there will be created implicit `function (event) { ... }` with your code placed inside.

I.e. in that case you have to use `event` (instead of `e`) as the name of the event object.